# png method error while using GD::Graph in Perl

Tags: perl, gd-graph

While compiling a perl script for making a graph and saving it into png file, I get the following error - 
Can't locate object method "png" via package "GD::Graph::bars" (perhaps you forgot to load "GD::Graph::bars"?)

Any idea how to solve it ?

The following is my code -

```
use CGI ':standard';
use GD::Graph::bars;
unlink("abc.png");
open (PIC, ">abc.png") or die "an error occurred: $!";
binmode PIC;

my @data = (["Jan", "Feb"],[23, 5]);

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::bars->new(500, 500);

$mygraph->set(
x_label     => 'Month',
y_label     => 'Number of Hits',
title       => 'Number of Hits in Each Month in 2002',) or warn $mygraph->error;

my $myimage = $mygraph->plot(\@data) or die $mygraph->error;

print PIC $mygraph->png;
close(PIC);
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of GD::Graph are you using?

Comment: I think it's the version of GD::Image, not GD::Graph that matters.

Comment: Neither GD::Graph nor GD::Image use that version format?!? `perl -e'use GD::Image 999'` is a quick way to find out.

Comment: Got the error - print PIC $mygraph->png; I need to use  print PIC $myimage->png;

Comment: ah, makes sense. Missed that :)

Comment: You should write your own answer and mark it as correct so the question shows up as completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the error - print PIC **$mygraph**->png; I need to use print PIC **$myimage**->png;